# Able to Switch the driver but not the focus

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver

**Scenario:** Lets say I have two tabs TAB1 and TAB2. I want to switch between these tabs based on certain criteria. With the below code I'm able to switch the driver between the tabs but tab focus is not getting changed.

Help me on this..Is there any possibility to achieve this?

```
public static Boolean SwitchWindow(string title)
{
    try
    {
        var currentWindow_title = Driver.Title;
        var currenhandle = Driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
        var availableWindows = new List<string>Driver.WindowHandles);

        if (currentWindow_title != title)
        {
            foreach (string w in availableWindows)
            {
                if (currenhandle != w)
                {
                    Driver.SwitchTo().Window(w);

                    var tit = Driver.Title;

                    if (Driver.Title == title)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "tab focus is not getting changed"? what exactly is happening?

Comment: Suppose I'm in TAB1 and I want my focus(from Users View now the Active  tab is TAB1) .Now I want my driver and focus to get switched to TAB2.When I use driver.switchto().window(windowhandle2),driver is  switching to TAB2 but from Users view still the display is in TAB1

Comment: Do you need any further information?

Answer (score 1):

If i am not wrong, you want to switch on child window.
Try this, hope this will help for you

```
    //storing parent window reference into string variable
String ParentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();

//switching from parent to pop up window
for (String Child_Window : driver.getWindowHandles())
{
driver.switchTo().window(Child_Window);

//implicit wait for visibility of pop up button
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

//explicit wait for visibility of pop up button
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);// 1 minute 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("??")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='??']")).click();
}
//Switching back to Parent Window
driver.switchTo().window(ParentWindow);
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: Its not working.Actually "driver.switchTo()" is switching my driver but not the focus of the tab.

Comment: @PrathyushaDwibhashi , try this to focus

Comment: JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
  jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('YourControlID').focus()");

Answer (score 0):

I tried Using JavaScript with window.focus() and it didnt work.PFB Code.

```
public static Boolean SwitchWindow(string title)
{
    var currentWindow_title = WebDriverUtilities3.WebDriver.Driver.Title;
    var currenhandle = WebDriverUtilities3.WebDriver.Driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
    var availableWindows = new List<string>(WebDriverUtilities3.WebDriver.Driver.WindowHandles);
    if (currentWindow_title != title)
    {
        foreach (string w in availableWindows)
        {
            if (currenhandle != w)
            {
                WebDriverUtilities3.WebDriver.Driver.SwitchTo().Window(w);

                IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)WebDriverUtilities3.WebDriver.Driver;

                string a = @"window.blur();
                window.focus();";

                try
                {
                    js.ExecuteScript(a);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
                js = null;

                var tit = WebDriverUtilities3.WebDriver.Driver.Title;

                if (WebDriverUtilities3.WebDriver.Driver.Title == title)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```