# Focus an Already opened tab in Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

I'm passing `SwitchURL` from my c# code. My main aim is I need to switch my focus to the Url (`SwitchURL`) i'm passing. Thanks in advance!!

```
 string SwitchURL = driver.Url;

 string a = @" window.url='" + SwitchURL + "';  window.blur();
 window.focus();)";     IJavaScriptExecutor js =
 (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver; js.ExecuteScript(a);
```

Comment: You need to get the window handle of the tab first using driver.WindlowHandle. Then use driver.SwitchTo().Window("Windowhandlename");

Comment: I already tried giving this.But I'm able to switch the driver but not the focus.So, Now I'm trying to switch the focus by using above code.Please see my post below(with this I'm able to switch the driver but not the focus)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41012975/able-to-switch-the-driver-but-not-the-focus